# css targeting submenu current-menu-item list item

Tags: css

Hi trying to target the only the first list item of a sub menu with current-menu-item class, but having no joy. Any help link to example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/makingthings/SPvCr/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the current menu item to be blue using this:

```
.current-menu-item li a{
color: blue
}
```